# Name error when trying to filter date field from base table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models

```
class Rule(models.Model):
 pmdruleid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
 effectivedate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

 class Meta:
  managed = False
  db_table = 'rule'

class Ruledefinitions(models.Model):
 ruleactivestatus = models.CharField(max_length=14)
 pmdclinicalruleid = models.OneToOneField(Rule, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='pmdclinicalruleid', primary_key=True)

 class Meta:
  managed = False
  db_table = 'ruledefinitions'
  unique_together = (('pmdclinicalruleid', 'pmdclinicalvariableid'),)
```

I am trying to filter records based on effectivedate field in viewset like below

```
class ActiveclientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Ruledefinitions.objects.select_related('pmdclinicalruleid').filter(pmdclinicalruleid__effectivedate < datetime.now())
```

I am getting `NameError: name 'pmdclinicalruleid__effectivedate' is not defined`.

Comment: try change to `pmdclinicalruleid__effectivedate__lt=datetime.now()`

Comment: Not working ...

Comment: same error? What error you have?

Comment: Sameerror .....

Answer (score 0):

I changed to

```
queryset = Ruledefinitions.objects.select_related('pmdclinicalruleid').filter(pmdclinicalruleid__effectivedate__lt = datetime.now())
```

It worked. The issue is when using lt there is no need to use > operator

Comment: what different with my comment?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps if you put single quotes around it?

```
queryset = Ruledefinitions.objects.select_related('pmdclinicalruleid').filter('pmdclinicalruleid__effectivedate' < datetime.now())
```

Comment: We cant do that comparing string and datetime.datetime

Comment: What if you try to manage a range ? something like ".filter(effectivedate__range=(startdate, futuredate)" ?